# change the color of check icon in select dropdown ant design

Tags: java, reactjs, typescript, dropdown, antd

In react project I have a select component (from antd) that can selects multiple options

I am trying to find a way that allows me to override the color of select field shadow (after displaying the dropdown) and the check icon next to checked options as indicated in the attached screenshot: [image]

I tried to override some ant classes like `.ant-select-item-option-content` and `.ant-select-selection-overflow-item .ant-select-selection-overflow-item-suffix` but no affect happened

and idea or solution would be Appreciated, Thank you

Comment: A lot of the time these libraries will have an API that lets you change their CSS. You don't want to change the css the way your doing it as if the library changes, you will lose your styles and wont know why.... you can find details at https://pro.ant.design/docs/style

Comment: @IWI is right and you should read this but if you want to continue to override your style the check icon class is `.anticon-check` just pass a color param to it and that's it but be careful if you add this class in a global style sheet, it can change the style for every check icon of your app

Comment: one solution with `[aria-selected]` [codeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-selection-render-antd4140-forked-x1wgx)